# Xamarin compiled 'Unsafe.As<bool, int>(ref test1)' returning different value if you drag on android touchscreen

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, monogame, unsafe

I'm currently building an Android app that basically looks like the old Windows95 Maze Screensaver. I'm using C# with Xamarin and MonoGame.
**Introduction (My maze generator in 3D)**

Here's a WASM compiled version in the browser:
http://devedse.softether.net:5003/

For some reason though I couldn't get the Release builds to work on my phone so I started diving into what was happening. Strange error after strange error later I finally pinpointed it on this piece of code:

```
var res1 = Unsafe.As<bool, int>(ref test1);
```

**Debug vs Release builds**

In a debug build within Xamarin this results in: `True -> 1 and False -> 0.`

If you run this code in a release build the results are different: `True -> -703131391 and False -> 0`

Here's the code I'm using to test this:

```
bool test1 = true;
bool test2 = false;

var res1 = Unsafe.As<bool, int>(ref test1);
var res2 = Unsafe.As<bool, int>(ref test2);

string helpStringToDraw =
    $"{n}{n}1: {test1} -> {res1} , 2: {test2} -> {res2}{n}" +
...
```

And here's some screenshots of the 2 builds.
Debug:
[image]

Release:
[image]

So this is basically my first issue.

**Touching the touch screen**

If however, you click on the touchscreen in the emulator and drag around the output of this code changes to the correct values. (wtf moment here).

I made a small video to show this: https://youtu.be/crzY-a2pb5I

**What to do?**

So hopefully someone can give me some advice whether this is a bug in Xamarin / C# or if this is expected behavior for Unsafe commands. Next to that I'd like to work around this in a way that wouldn't impact performance. (Just for the heck of it I'm trying to write a maze generator that tries to be as fast as possible by doing as much micro-optimizations and introducing an if-check that would generate branching actually slows down the algorithm a little).

Comment: If I were to guess, Debug mode initializes all 32 bits of the `bool` to 0 then applies the new values. This requires an extra operation, if the declaration has an initializing value. In release mode only the required bit is set or cleared.

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.unsafe.as?view=net-6.0

> The behavior of Unsafe.As(o) is only well-defined if the typical
> "safe" casting operation (T)o would have succeeded. Use of this API to
> circumvent casts that would otherwise have failed is unsupported and
> could result in runtime instability.

If I correctly understand your code, your T is `(bool, int)` and clearly it violates the rule above.

As such this is something that is expected to fail sometimes in .NET, not just Xamarin.